# Get the data-url correctly using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a delete comment function and 
this are the pieces of html for a delete comment functionality.

```
<div id="comment-area">
  <div class="list-border">
    <small class="mdl-button delete-comment js-delete-comment pull-right" data-url="http://myproject.com/comment_controller/delete_comment/12/6">
      x
    </small>
  </div>
  <div class="list-border">
    <small class="mdl-button delete-comment js-delete-comment pull-right" data-url="http://myproject.com/comment_controller/delete_comment/13/6">
      x
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the function for delete a comment, which is automatically loaded when document is ready,

```
function delete_comment () {
  $('.delete-comment').click( function (e) {
    var url = $('.delete-comment').attr('data-url');
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        $('#comment-area').html(data.comments);
        delete_comment();
      },
      error: function () {
        alert('error');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The problem with this function from the given html above, if I'm going to click on `.delete-comment` with 
`data-url="http://myproject.com/comment_controller/delete_comment/13/6"` take note on this `"13/6"`, the javascript function `delete_comment()`,
in this line

`var url = $('.delete-comment').attr('data-url');`

chose to get the `data-url="http://myproject.com/comment_controller/delete_comment/12/6"` take note also this `"12/6"`, to see the difference, instead of the `data-url` of `.delete-comment` I clicked.

In short, this function always chose the `first-child div small`, whatever `small.delete-comment` I'm going to click.

What was the best solution for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
```

You are getting the `attribue value` by `className` and `multiple elements` have same `class` so the `attribute value` for `first element` found in `dom` is being returned.

So you need to get the `value` of `element` which is `clicked` and you can use `this` to get the `value` of clicked `element`.

Answer (score 2):

A more robust way to approach this would be to use the jQuery [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function.

```
var url = $(this).data('url');
```

This will pick up any dynamically added/updated url that may have changed via JavaScript, but not updated in the DOM attribute.